# Can you open commits in TortoiseHG from web browser link?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

TortoiseHG has built-in URLs to link to other changesets.

Is there a URI scheme to use these from a web browser? Something like `hg://cset:tip`?

That way you could have a clickable link from the web browser straight to the changeset you need...

Alternatively, how hard would it be to implement something like this, for Chrome, Firefox, and IE?

Comment: Is that all the information the link contains? If so, then II don'tthink that it can be done. You'd need the repo path to be able to use the link from outside TortoiseHg.

Comment: Well, the link can be whatever. I can add the repo path. I was just wanting to be able to do something with the link once I have it. The idea is to use the link from our custom-built Helpdesk ticketing system

Comment: The problem with using TortoiseHg for this is that the helpdesk people would need the repo on their machines.  Are your Mercurial repositories held on a central server?  If so, do you use `hgweb`?  We use `hgweb` for our central server and can go to `http://hg.server/path/to/repo/rev/71745da8b9b3` to view changeset `71745da8b9b3` on a particular repository.

Comment: That'll work! I forgot about hgweb. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. I've added that solution as an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with using TortoiseHg for this is that the helpdesk people would need the repo on their machines.

If your Mercurial repositories are held on a central server and you use `hgweb` then you already have this feature available to you. You can go to `http://hg.server/path/to/repo/rev/71745da8b9b3` to view changeset `71745da8b9b3` on a particular repository for example.